# Does didFinishLaunchingWithOptions happens after certain application "exits"?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Does didFinishLaunchingWithOptions happens after:

1. applicationWillResignActive
2. applicationDidEnterBackground
3. applicationWillEnterForeground

Or does it happen only after applicationWillTerminate?

And when applicationDidBecomeActive happens then? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> It is called after your application has been launched and its main nib
>   file has been loaded. At the time this method is called, your
>   application is in the inactive state. At some point after this method
>   returns, a subsequent delegate method is called to move your
>   application to the active (foreground) state or the background state.

It happens when the user opens your app. Followed by applicationDidBecomeActive when the app is ready to receive user events.

When the user presses the home button the following methods are called (by this order):
- applicationWillResignActive
- applicationDidEnterBackground

When the user opens your app again, and it is in background:

- applicationWillEnterForeground
- applicationDidBecomeActive

Finally, applicationWillTerminate is called instead of applicationDidEnterBackground on devices with iOS 3.x or earlier. Or with devices that do not support background apps (like the 3G).

Answer (score 0):

```
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

only fires once: when your program starts up. You should typically create the main window/view controller here.